# How to remove attributes from tags inside Vue components?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

I want to use `data-test` attributes (as suggested [here](https://blog.kentcdodds.com/making-your-ui-tests-resilient-to-change-d37a6ee37269)), so when running tests I can reference tags using these attributes.

```
  <template>
    <div class="card-deck" data-test="container">content</div>
  </template>
```

The element will be found using:

```
document.querySelector('[data-test="container"]')
// and not using: document.querySelector('.card-deck')
```

But I don't want these `data-test` attributes to get to production, I need to remove them. How can I do that? (There are [babel](https://github.com/kutyel/babel-plugin-remove-test-ids) [plugins](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/babel-plugin-react-remove-properties) that do that for react.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution (for a Nuxt.js project), provided by [Linus Borg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339840/linus-borg) in this [thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-remove-attributes-from-tags-inside-vue-components/24138/), is:

```
// nuxt.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  build:   {
    // ...
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // ...
      const vueLoader = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.loader === 'vue-loader')
      vueLoader.options.compilerModules = [{
        preTransformNode(astEl) {
          if (!ctx.dev) {
            const {attrsMap, attrsList} = astEl
            tagAttributesForTesting.forEach((attribute) => {
              if (attrsMap[attribute]) {
                delete attrsMap[attribute]
                const index = attrsList.findIndex(x => x.name === attribute)
                attrsList.splice(index, 1)
              }
            })
          }
          return astEl
        },
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

where `tagAttributesForTesting` is an array with all attributes to be removed, like: `["data-test", ":data-test", "v-bind:data-test"]`.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who want to know how to do this is vanilla Vue 3, read on.

According to the [Vue CLI documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader), the correct way to override a loader's options is to use the `chainWebpack` method within your Vue configuration (within your `vue.config.js` file):

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack(config) {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap((options) => {
        options.compilerOptions.modules = [{
          preTransformNode(element) {
            if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') return

            const { attrsMap, attrsList } = element;

            if ('data-test' in attrsMap) {
              delete attrsMap[attribute];

              const index = attrsList.findIndex(x => x.name === attribute);
              attrsList.splice(index, 1)
            }

            return element;
          }
        }];

        return options;
      });
  }
};
```

For your particular use case, I think the most maintenance free option would be to use a pattern matching strategy to remove test attributes.  This would keep you from having to add every new test attribute to the list of blacklisted attributes:

```js
{
  preTransformNode(element) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') return

    const { attrsMap, attrsList } = element;

    for (const attribute in attrsMap) {
      // For example, you could add a unique prefix to all of your test
      // attributes (e.g. "data-test-***") and then check for that prefix
      // using a Regular Expression
      if (/^data-test/.test(attribute)) {
        delete attrsMap[attribute];

        const index = attrsList.findIndex(x => x.name === attribute);
        attrsList.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }

    return element;
  }
}
```

Note that the attributes **will** include any Vue directives (e.g. "v-bind:") that you attach to them, so be sure to compensate for that if you decide to identify your test attributes using unique prefixes.

I think it would be best to mention that, just like @ahwo before me, I drew my inspiration from [Linus Borg's suggestion](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-remove-attributes-from-tags-inside-vue-components/24138/3) on the Vue forums.

P.s. With Vue, it's possible to create attributes that have [dynamic names](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamic-attribute-names/4926/2).  I think this would be useful to know for anyone who is adding attributes for testing